# Did I Kill My Laptop?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, dc, laptop

My laptop takes a 19V adapter but I accidentally plugged in a 12V adapter and the laptop started smoking. I unplugged it after about a second. I read that if the polarity is correct and the voltage is lower on the adapter than the requirement of the laptop that it's OK. Why did it start smoking? Did I irreparably damage the laptop?

Comment: it is not possible to answer your questions without opening the laptop and checking to see what smoked ... any failure can be repaired

Comment: your question is not and eiectronics design question, so it does not belong here

Comment: That sounds very strange. What make an model? Are you 10 000 percent sure the polarity is correct?

Comment: If smoke came out of your laptop then the answer to the question is *probably* "yes"

Answer (score 1):

Probably. The 2/3 normal voltage might cause 100% duty cycle operation of the battery charger, meaning current SOARS far beyond tolerable operating currents.

Your switching FET may have smoked. Or the energy_transfer inductor may have gone into saturation, overheating either the inductor or the FET.

Comment: That's one crappy battery charger if it can't gracefully handle overcurrent though...

Comment: @Lundin Or undervoltage! How did it even handle startup and shutdown of the charger without UVLO?